# Can I have a folder instead file for a Django custom command?

Tags: python, django, command, structure, customization

The only way I know to create a custom Django command is by putting the file in the `project/app/management/commands` folder like this `project/app/management/commands/my_custom_command.py`

But I would like to know if there is a way to make a directory (like a python package) instead of a single file. It should be something like this:

```
project
├── app
|   ├── management
|   |   └── commands
|   |       ├── my_custom_command
|   |       |   ├── __init__.py
|   |       |   └── ... (other stuff like settings and output files)
|   |       └── ...
|   └── ...
├── manage.py
└── ...
```

There is a way to do something like that? I think it is possible to use a whole app folder to do something similar by saving the command stuff in the app folder, but I don't like that solution.

Clarification: I already tried using a folder with the `__init__.py` file but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible, packages are excluded, see `django.core.management.find_commands`

In Django 3.1.5 it is:

```
def find_commands(management_dir):
    """
    Given a path to a management directory, return a list of all the command
    names that are available.
    """
    command_dir = os.path.join(management_dir, 'commands')
    return [name for _, name, is_pkg in pkgutil.iter_modules([command_dir])
            if not is_pkg and not name.startswith('_')]
```